# Receive UDP message using CANoe and C#

Tags: c#, canoe

we're trying to set up a test bench in Vector's CANoe for a ECU that uses BroadR-Reach. Therefore, we want to send and receive UDP messages. We tried with the UdpClient class and the BeginSend/BeginReceive methods. Sending messages works, but for some reasons the execution of the test node stops when we try to receive a message.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Vector.Tools;
using Vector.CANoe.Runtime;
using Vector.CANoe.Threading;
using Vector.CANoe.TFS;
using Vector.CANoe.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using NetworkDB;

public class TestPingBroadRReach1 : TestModule
{
    private byte channel = 6;
    private ushort pingCount = 0;
    public static bool messageReceived = false;

    public struct UdpState
    {
        public UdpClient u;
        public IPEndPoint e;
    }

    public override void Main()
    {
        // Test sequence definition
        PingTest();
    }

    [TestCase("SYS4_TC4321", "BroadR-Reach 1: Ping test", "Checks if a ping is answered on BroadR-Reach 1")]
    public void PingTest()
    {
        // setup UDP client

        Report.TestStep("Setup UDP client.");
        IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0xC09F);
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(e);

        UdpState s = new UdpState();
        s.e = e;
        s.u = udpClient;

        IAsyncResult receiveResult = udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UdpReceiveFinished), s);


        //UdpClient u = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"), 0xC09F));
        UdpClient u = new UdpClient();
        byte[] pingRequest = this.CreatePingRequest();

        // send the message
        // the destination is defined by the server name and port
        u.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.80"), 0xBB9));
        u.BeginSend(pingRequest, pingRequest.Length, new AsyncCallback(UdpSendFinished), u);

        int i = 0;
        while (!messageReceived && i < 50)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            ++i;
        }

    private void UdpSendFinished(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        UdpClient u = (UdpClient)result.AsyncState;
        Output.WriteLine("UdpSendFinished");
        u.EndSend(result);
    }

    private void UdpReceiveFinished(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient u = ((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
        IPEndPoint e = ((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;
        byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
        Output.WriteLine("UdpReceiveFinished");
        messageReceived = true;
    }
}
```

Does anybody has an example for receiving UDP messages with CANoe and C#? That would be great, thank's!

Comment: There is a demo configuration called _UDPBasicDotNet_ coming with CANoe. This configuration contains an example implementation of a UDP Server and a UDP client in C#. Did you already check those?

Comment: Hey M. Spiller, I didn't know those examples. Thank 's for the tip. I will give a look at it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @M.Spiller and mwolfart. Could you share the CANOe example? I don't find it. Thank you!